# Access data structure from SonarQube widget

Tags: widget, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm building a SonarQube plugin which gives some stats about a few ETL scripts, I've followed this tutorial: https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/sonarqube-plugins-2/ and the plugin is already working; however, I've one important problem with it: I can't use my own data structures in this plugin.

I'm able to define and use data structures in the Java backend, but I can't call that structure from the .erb HTML file, I can use some Ruby there but at the moment I haven't being able to figure out how to call a data structur, for example a HashMap, from the widget view.

I'd really appreciate assistance in this topic, I've checked SonarQube website but their documentation is really poor.

Comment: "...documentation is really poor"... _on this topic_ ;)

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't seems it's is going to change anytime soon: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-1678 :(